# PySide QtTreeWidget first column srretches

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am using PySide and I have a QtTreeWidget with 8 header columns. The first column contains check boxes only, but the first column expands more than it should.  Is there something I am missing?

Comment: what do you mean "more than is should"? Can you give an example?